# job for openfire . service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: openfire

I have server with Cent OS 7.2 and install open java 1.8.0_65

```
I am trying to install openfire XMPP.
```

i have installed successfully but when i m going to start service. it is throwing an error.

job for `openfire.service` failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. see

```
 "systemctl status openfire.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

how should i overcome? please help me

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

This solved it for me.

Comment: Please elaborate it a bit details, otherwise it will be closed as a comment written on the section.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and issue.  Setting the correct JAVA_HOME in /etc/sysconfig/openfire fixed the problem (at least for me). Snip from file:

```
# If you wish to override the auto-detected JAVA_HOME variable, uncomment
# and change the following line.
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64
```